# Swift application unable to find ObservableObject after XCode 11.4.1 patch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm really not even entirely sure how to word this post, or what code to provide in order to help assist others with determining what the issue is. I just updated my XCode to the latest version, and built my app again without having made any changes from my previous build made on the last version. All of a sudden, with this latest build, I keep getting a fatal error when trying to navigate to part of my application.

I have an EnvironmentObject called profile which is generated when the user logs into the app. As one would expect, I use this frequently for retrieving user data. The exact view being problematic is my profile view, which essentially is based entirely off of profile data. I know that the EnvironmentObject is defined and created successfully, because the landing view after logging in utilizes this object for bits and pieces. However, to get to the profile you have to navigate to a specific section of the UI, which is a NavigationLink into the profile.

When I hit this navigation link in the latest version of XCode, it throws a fatal error telling me the observable object of which the environment object is derived from does not exist, which, as is obvious from the fact the main landing view loads, is false. To be specific about the error, it prints to console that

> No ObservableObject of type ProfileFetcher found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ProfileFetcher may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0

Now of course, this error is incorrect, because this observable object does most certainly exist, and is used in the view before it.

I even tried to just make the view not reliant on the object and just try to pass the profile object data onto the view by using a variable, to no avail.

Like I said, this build with all of this code exactly as it is worked perfectly fine on the last version of XCode, and the fact that now my application is broken because of some bug is extremely infuriating and I don't know what to do to fix it, because the environment object is attached to every base view I have, not just the ones that are ancestors of the profile view, so I know this isn't true.

I really don't know what to do except wait for the next update and hope it fixes this, because this object is used in literally every view I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels fast to post an answer but I figured it out, and perhaps it's my fault for not reading the patch notes because they changed something regarding the use of environmentobjects in subviews. Now, when you call a navigationlink to another view that utilizes an environment object, you have to pass it along with the view by using NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView().environmentObject(profile)). If you don't, you will receive the same error I did. Hope this helped somebody out.